# How do I prevent my disk from being bloated?

Tags: macos, catalina

What is "Other" and how do I prevent it from being bloated? I'm having to back up and format my hard drive every year due this happening.  As you can see, I have very little of everything else.  I mainly use some IDE's and web browsers and that's pretty much it. I'm using Catalina at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "review files" option to the right of that list it should let you see a break down of your files to help you make decisions and see what is taking up space on your volume.

Comment: It doesn't show anything about `Other` though.  It shows you things like `Large Files`, `Downloads`, `Unsupported Apps`, and `File Browser`, all of which compose of about 15GB only.

Comment: I don't show "Other" in my listing, so I can't try this out to see if it works, but this article seems to discuss it: https://www.igeeksblog.com/what-is-other-on-mac-storage/